# C++ program with Open MPI doesn't work without internet connection

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

There is a problem with MPI - program works when there is an internet connection on my PC, but doesn't work without it.

I got this error:

> It looks like `orte_init` failed for some reason; your parallel
>   process is likely to abort. There are many reasons that a parallel
>   process can fail during `orte_init`; some of which are due to
>   configuration or environment problems. This failure appears to be an
>   internal failure; here's some additional information (which may only
>   be relevant to an Open MPI developer):
>
> > orte_rml_base_select failed
> >     --> Returned value Error (-1) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS

What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: Looks like you probably need to turn off some of the BTLs. It's been a while since I used Open MPI, but as I recall, you might try turning of tcp and leaving on self and sm.

Comment: Try running with `mpiexec --mca btl ^tcp --mca oob ^tcp ...` though it would have helped if you'd have given more details like OS, list of interfaces, etc.

Comment: Do you mean no internet connectivity or you just disable your network interface?